# How can upload a image from system to angular project without browsing the image instead of clicking one button?

Tags: html, angular

My aim is to upload a image from local system (means a specified folder) into my angular project ,Without browsing  and using a button function i need to get the image into my project,,So when the card reader reads the card automatically a folder would generate in c , i wanna take image from there
anyone know about it?

Comment: To clarify: you mean YOUR local system or a USERs local system? And by project do you mean the files locally on your computer, the website/webapp running in the browser, or your project files on a server?

Comment: My intention is to upload a image from a particular folder in c , So its for all users

Comment: You intend to launch your angular website or web app and have a visitor click a button that automatically uploads a file from a location on their computer that you pre-define?

Comment: its not like that, software is for local permise ,So when the card reader reads the card automatically a folder would generate in c , i wanna take image from there

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. And you want the angular project running in the browser to do that? Grab the image from the folder in C? Unfortunately JavaScript running in the browser has no access to anything outside the browser, for the users safety.

Comment: oh oh , is there no way to achieve?

Comment: In a `<form>` you can give the user an `<input type="file">` but they have to choose the file themselves. Otherwise you need to get them to download a program onto their computer that finds the file and sends it where you need it, but that program isn't JavaScript :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this piece of code from  here you can upload files from your local system.

```
selectAFile: File = null;

  onFileSelection(event) {
    this.selectAFile = <File>event.target.files[0]
  }
```

now upload function and select a storage place

```
upload() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.selectAFile, this.selectAFile.name);
    this.http.post('storageplacelink', fd).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify where these snippets go? The filename or file type, and in what part of the project?

Comment: its the common way of uploading an image from local system to project,my intention is different